# Algorithm for mapping segment with floating point vertices onto 2D integer space (pseudo-pixels)

Tags: algorithm, graphics, floating-point, rendering

I want to render a line segment onto a virtual integer space in minimum average time for any segment orientation/length. The segment is defined by two points with real number values (doubles).

I have already come up with several ideas that would probably work, but they strike me as horrific, heuristic hacks. (I.e. There is a clear "better direction" to begin from depending on orientation of the segment).

Surely there is a better way than the brute force method (find the "long" direction (x- or y-axis) between the end points then step along each integer value along that axis and round the value in the orthogonal axis to determine exactly one pixel (integer point) location at every integer value along the "long" axis.)

Comment: You should define what it means to render a line segment. Suppose each element in the space is a square containing all the points nearer to its coordinates than to any other coordinates (where do ties go?). Do you want to draw a pixel in each element that contains at least one point of the line? What intensity should the pixel have (greater if it has more points of the line)? Or should the number of pixels drawn be in some ratio to the length of the line (e.g., roughly one pixel per one unit length)? Or some other criterion?

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's exactly how I pictured the problem - a square around each integer point containing all the real-valued points that would round/snap to that integer point, and real-valued lines crossing over those squares. I hadn't thought of varying intensity as you suggest, and for my application it's not necessary, but it is a good thing to keep in mind, thanks (and +1 for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say regarding the "better direction" reminds me of the Bresenham line algorithm, is this maybe what you want?
http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html

[edit]

The difference with non-integer endpoints wasn't obvious to me but there's an illustration [here](http://www.antigrain.com/doc/introduction/introduction.agdoc.html#SUBPIXEL_BRESENHAM).

As you're drawing one pixel per integer span on the long axis I'm assuming your drawing points with equal intensity (no antialiasing).

So you can just implement bresenham without the integer optimisation (what you did already) and round points at the end.
Or use fixed point math through integer bresenham (i.e. multiply your coordinates by 65536 and round, run bresenham with a longer step on the long axis, and divide or shift the output points back down to the required values before drawing).

But depending whether you are drawing fonts, or tesellated curves, or wireframe rectangles it might look better with straight bresenhams or with an antialiasing algorithm.

Comment: Aside from the optimization to make this integer operations, this is very close to what I came up with. The optimization is nice - but for my use I'm not guaranteed that the endpoints are in integer space - so I don't think the optimzation can be applied. +1 for keying on the "better direction" clue to lead me to this. Any other suggestions for segments that don't have endpoints on an integer grid? (other than the brute-force method of rounding at each crossing of the segement with the integer grid orthagonal to the "long direction" of the segment).

Comment: That link is just what I have in mind. It discusses "Bresenham Line with Subpixel Accuracy" but doesn't go into how it is done. I have implemented a brute-force method using real numbers and rounding at each integer pixel value. That's not using Bresenham's optimization at all, so based on the name of the topic in the link you posted, I'm inclined to think some optimization is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the equation of the line that relates the X and Y values. and then evaluate it at each integer x coordinate.  This will give you the y coordinate as a float which you can then round off and draw.

Comment: +1 That's the algorithm that I came up with (with the added step of determining the "long" direction). I will have to see just how expensive a round() operation is if I use this brute-force method.